# file store in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to store `pdf` files in the `mysql` database. But I am getting some errors.

This is my html --

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="content" name="content" accept=".pdf">
```

this is my PHP code --

```
$contents = file_get_contents($_FILES['content']);
```

But I am always getting this error ---

> Notice:  Undefined index: content in **$contents =
>   file_get_contents($_FILES['content']);**
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in  **$contents =
>   file_get_contents($_FILES['content']);**

what am I doing wrong, How can I fix this problem.

Comment: Read manuals about file uploading. Internet has a lot of them.

Comment: something similar to this might work for you `$result = mysql_query 'INSERT INTO table (data) VALUES (\'' . mysql_real_escape_string (file_get_contents ('/path/to/the/file/to/store.pdf')) . '\');';`

Comment: While there's nothing fundamentally wrong with storing files in a database, I would point out that it's much more common to find files stored in a file system

Comment: Done formatting, grammar checks, removed extra special characters.

Comment: `print_r` and `var_dump` are your best friends.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your form has `enctype` attribute and its value is `multipart/form-data`. Without it you will be getting empty `$_FILE` variable.

To read more about enctype see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp